How to make custom table component searchable
I followed a tutorial to create this table component, but I have tried everything to make it searchable but to no avail. the table component has a pagination.
table component
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "./table.css";

const Table = (props) => {
  const initDataShow =
    props.limit && props.bodyData
      ? props.bodyData.slice(0, Number(props.limit))
      : props.bodyData;

  const [dataShow, setDataShow] = useState(initDataShow);

  let pages = 1;

  let range = [];

  if (props.limit !== undefined) {
    let page = Math.floor(props.bodyData.length / Number(props.limit));
    pages = props.bodyData.length % Number(props.limit) === 0 ? page : page + 1;
    range = [...Array(pages).keys()];
  }

  const [currPage, setCurrPage] = useState(0);

  const selectPage = (page) => {
    const start = Number(props.limit) * page;
    const end = start + Number(props.limit);

    setDataShow(props.bodyData.slice(start, end));

    setCurrPage(page);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="table-wrapper">
        <table>
          {props.headData && props.renderHead ? (
            <thead>
              <tr>
                {props.headData.map((item, index) =>
                  props.renderHead(item, index)
                )}
              </tr>
            </thead>
          ) : null}
          {props.bodyData && props.renderBody ? (
            <tbody>
              {dataShow.map((item, index) => props.renderBody(item, index))}
            </tbody>
          ) : null}
        </table>
      </div>
      {pages > 1 ? (
        <div className="table__pagination">
          {range.map((item, index) => (
            <div
              key={index}
              className={`table__pagination-item ${
                currPage === index ? "active" : ""
              }`}
              onClick={() => selectPage(index)}
            >
              {item + 1}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Table;


Usage, I created a sample usage of the component, would have loved to add the styles but stackoverflow error of too much codes
const App=()=>{

  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
const allUsers = [
    {
      id: 1,
      firstName: "Jon",
      lastName: "Doe",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      firstName: "Jane",
      lastName: "Doe",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      firstName: "Left",
      lastName: "Hem",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      firstName: "Yusuf",
      lastName: "Hem",
  ];
const customerTableHead = ["", "name", "email"];
  const renderHead = (item, index) => <th key={index}>{item}</th>;

  const renderBody = (item, index) => (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td className="pointer">{index + 1}</td>
      <td className="pointer" >
        {item?.lastName + " " + item?.firstName}
      </td>
      <td className="pointer">
        {item?.lastName  + item?.firstName + "@gmail.com"}
      </td>
    
    </tr>
  );
  let filteredItems = allUsers?.filter((item) =>
    item.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
  );
return(
<div>
   <input
          type="text"
          value={search}
          onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Search here..."
        />
   <Table
     limit="4"
     headData={customerTableHead}
     renderHead={(item, index) => renderHead(item, index)}
     bodyData={filteredItems}
     renderBody={(item, index) => renderBody(item, index)}
   />
</div>
)
}

Any help is welcome, thanks

After awhile, i noticed the issue was the new data wasn't rendering. So I added Useeffect hook and use the search value as a dependency. So that as it changes the table data changes
Codes added to the table component
  useEffect(() => {
    setDataShow(initDataShow);
  }, [initDataShow, props.search]);

and the used component looks like this now

<Table
    limit="10"
    headData={customerTableHead}
    search={search}
    renderHead={(item, index) => renderHead(item, index)}
    bodyData={filteredItems}
    renderBody={(item, index) => renderBody(item, index)}
/>

